# Email Alert script to check for user to be notified - Google AppScript

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script

I found a lot of useful stuff in this forum. I am new to GAS and JS coding in general and I cannot find a way to solve something that I am confident it's NBD.

I am attaching the code first:

```
function emailAlert() { 
   
  // today's date information
  var today = new Date();
  var todayMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var todayDay = today.getDate();
  var todayYear = today.getFullYear();

  // getting data from spreadsheet
  var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Assignments");
  var resultssn = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getName();

//Emails addresses
  var emailJonDoe = "example@example.com"
  var emailEmilyDoe = "example@example.com"
  
  var duedatesRange = sheet.getRange("H5:H9");  
  var duedates = duedatesRange.getValues();
  var actionitRange = sheet.getRange("C5:C9"); 
  var actionit = actionitRange.getValues();
  var prjsRange = sheet.getRange("B5:B9"); 
  var prjs = prjsRange.getValues();
  var whosRange = sheet.getRange("D5:D9"); 
  var whos = actionitRange.getValues();


  //looping through all of the rows
  for (var i = 0; i < duedates.length; ++i) {
    var row = duedates[i];
    
  for (var i = 0; i < actionit.length; ++i) {  
    var assignmenttext = actionit[i];
    
  for (var i = 0; i < prjs.length; ++i) {     
    var project = prjs[i];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < whos.length; ++i) {      
    var user = whos[i];

    var expireDateFormat = Utilities.formatDate(
      new Date(row[i]),
      'ET',
      'MM/dd/yyyy'
    );

    // email information
    var subject = '';
    var message =
      " One of your action items is due today. " +
      '\n' +
      '\n' +
      ' Project: ' +
      project[i] +
      '\n' +
      '\n' +
      ' Action Item: ' +
      assignmenttext[i] +
      '\n' + 
      '\n' +
      'Check the Tracker now !!' + 
      '\n' +
      url;

    //expiration date information
    var expireDateMonth = new Date(row[i]).getMonth() + 1;
    var expireDateDay = new Date(row[i]).getDate();
    Logger.log("Expire date is:" + expireDateDay);

    //check for JD and send email to him if true
    if (
      user[i] === "JD" &&
      expireDateMonth === todayMonth &&
      expireDateDay === todayDay
    ) {
      var subject =
        'FEG AAAAAAManagement - An action item is due today!! : ' + assignmenttext[i];
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailJonDoe, subject, message);
      Logger.log('todayyyy!');
    }
    
    //check for ED and send email to him if true
    if (
      user[i] === "ED" &&
      expireDateMonth === todayMonth &&
      expireDateDay === todayDay
    ) {
      var subject =
        'FEG DDDDDManagement - An action item is due today!! : ' + assignmenttext[i];
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailEmilyDoe, subject, message);
      Logger.log('todayyyy!');
    }
    }
 }
 }
}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycOqe.png)

This is a simple snippet that send emails for each row that contains today's date in column H.

I have a similar one already working but I would like to implement the "user" feature.
Long story short, I want the code to:

1. Check for for each row that contains today's date in column H.
2. For each of above rows, check the content of it's respective cell in column D.
   If it contains JD, send email alert to JD's email. If it contains ED, send email alert to ED's email.
3. The email should contain row's respective cell for column C (assignmenttext) and column B (project).

AFAIK, this code is not too heavy on the server side since I only "getRange" at the beginning and most of the code runs on the client side (is this correct?).

I am not confident with which loop function to use in this case and how to implement it with my code.

I am open to any comment or suggestion. Thanks in advance to anyone who would spend some time to help me. (:

Comment: It’s funny that you should say that you can’t find such a solution on Stack Overflow because email questions are some of the most abundant on Stack Overflow. My first impression would be that you probably didn’t look too hard.

Comment: Hi Cooper. I did look through the email feature threads in this forum. The issue is more about loops rather than the Send email function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sort of thing I would have done.  Admittedly you have to be comfortable with dealing with arrays but it makes for a nice compact code.

The two objects emails and prefix provide a place to enter new users all in one place and simplify the code by allow you to use a single send command.

```
function emailAlert() { 
  const sentcolumn=45;//I recommend adding some column to contain and indication of when an email is already been sent.
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName("Assignments");
  const vA=sh.getRange(5,1,5,sentcolumn).getValues();//your data went from row 5 to row 9 that is five rows  
  const dt=new Date();
  const today=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();//this is a number
  const emails={"JD":"jd@example.com","ED":"ed@example.com"};//emails
  const prefix={"JD":"FEG AAAAAAManagement - An action item is due today!! : ","ED":"FEG DDDDDManagement - An action item is due today!! : "};//subject prefixes
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    let x=new Date(r[7]);
    let duedate=new Date(x.getFullYear(),x.getMonth()+1,x.getDate()).valufOf();//this is a number
    var body=Utilities.formatString('One of your action items is due today. \n\n Project: %s \n\n Action Item: %s\n\nCheck the Tracker now !!\n%s',r[1],R[2],ss.getUrl());
    let subject=prefix[r[3]] + r[2];
    if(today==duedate && r[sentcolumn-1]!='Sent') {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(emails[r[3]],subject,body);
      sh.getRange(i+5,sentcolumn).setValue('Sent');//adding something like this would keep you from sending duplicate emails by mistake
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using a single for loop, checking data in each row:

```
function sendEmail() {
   
  // today's date information
  var today = new Date();
  var todayMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var todayDay = today.getDate();
  var todayYear = today.getFullYear();
  Logger.log(todayDay);

  // getting data from spreadsheet
  var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Assignments");
  var resultssn = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getName();

  //Emails addresses
  var emailJonDoe = "example@example.com"
  var emailEmilyDoe = "example@example.com"
  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,8).getValues();

  //looping through all of the rows
  for (var i = 0; i < lastRow-1; i++) {
    var project = dataRange[i][1];
    var assignmenttext = dataRange[i][2];
    var user = dataRange[i][3];
    var row = dataRange[i][7]; 
    
    //expiration date information
    var expireDateFormat = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row),'ET','MM/dd/yyyy');
    var expireDateMonth = new Date(row).getMonth() + 1;
    var expireDateDay = new Date(row).getDate();
    Logger.log("Expire date is:" + expireDateDay);
    
    //check for expiry date
    if (expireDateMonth === todayMonth && expireDateDay === todayDay) {
      var subject =
        'FEG AAAAAAManagement - An action item is due today!! : ' + assignmenttext;
          // email information
      var message =
          " One of your action items is due today. " +
          '\n' +
          '\n' +
          ' Project: ' +
          project +
          '\n' +
          '\n' +
          ' Action Item: ' +
          assignmenttext +
          '\n' + 
          '\n' +
          'Check the Tracker now !!' + 
          '\n' +
          url;
      if (user === 'JD') {
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailJonDoe, subject, message);
      }
      if (user === 'ED') {
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailEmilyDoe, subject, message);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Running this on a sample sheet returns:

[image]

[image]

Note that I did not send emails, instead I just logged values in my test code.